# Git: Waiting for your editor to close the file

Tags: git

I started to merge changes to a new branch on `git` while editing some files with `emacs` (the default editor) on the previous branch in another terminal.

I got the following error message:

```
hint: Waiting for your editor to close the file... /usr/bin/emacs: /cvmfs/cms.cern.ch/slc7_amd64_gcc820/cms/cmssw/CMSSW_10_6_0/external/slc7_amd64_gcc820/lib/libtiff.so.5: no version information available (required by /usr/bin/emacs)
```

First, it is not clear from this error message, what is the file in question.

Second, after closing `emacs` in the other terminal, the branch checkout process does not move forward.

What to do in this situation?

Comment: It's probably open somewhere else?

Comment: usually I get this when it is waiting on me for a merge message which has to be provided in the editor. What is your default editor? Check that is waiting on a merge message to be provided.

Comment: Wild guess: it's waiting for emacs to finish editing the commit message and emacs has fallen over because of the missing libtiff.so.5 thing? So... configure git to use a different editor?

Comment: Generic oversized debugging hammer `strace -f <command>` (or its equivalent on different systems). It will produce a ton of output but if you look just before the error message, it will tell you which file failed and how the failure was detected.

Comment: What does `git var GIT_EDITOR` show?

Answer (score 0):

Probably because the emacs server is down. Activate with the following command.

```
systemctl --user enable emacs # enable emacs server
systemctl --user start emacs # start emacs server
```

see also [emacs manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Emacs-Server.html)